# update php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I try to update my query and it seems there is no problem and there is no error but I don't know why the subjects on the sidebar doesn't update, please help me (I'm sure there is no problem in other code pages)

```
<?php include("includes/connections.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/function.php"); ?>
    <?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $errors = array();
            $required_fields = array('menu_name', 'position', 'visible');
            foreach($required_fields as $fieldname){
                if (!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || empty($_POST[$fieldname]) && $_POST[$fieldname] != 0){
                    $errors[] = $fieldname;
                }
            }
            $field_width_lengths = array('menu_name' => 30);
            foreach ($field_width_lengths as $fieldname => $maxlength) {
                if (strlen(trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection , $_POST[$fieldname]))) > $maxlength){
                    $errors[] = $fieldname;
                }
            }
            if (empty($errors)){
         $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['subj']);
         $menu_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['menu_name']);
         $position = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['position']);
         $visible = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['visible']);
         $query = "UPDATE subjects SET
                    menu_name = '{$menu_name}'
                    position = {$position}
                    visible = {$visible}
                    WHERE id = {$id}";
         $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        } else {
            echo "error dade";
        }
     }

    else{ //if error occurs
    }
    ?>
    </nav>
    <?php find_selected_page(); ?>
        <?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
    <?php navigation($sel_subj, $sel_pages); ?>
    <section>
    ...
    </section>
<?php require("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

I would be appreciate to help me I searched about this problem but can't find anything about my problem.

Comment: `echo` your query and try to execute it in mysql, if there will be error or not update entry - problem is in query string, also re-check your `$connection`

Comment: @user1954544 when I use print_r it also doesnt show anything but if I echo something to check the condition`s performance it works , I checked $connection and It seems okey (I used it in other pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 $query = "UPDATE subjects SET
                    menu_name = '{$menu_name}',
                    position = {$position},
                    visible = {$visible}
                    WHERE id = {$id}";
```

put `,` for every column name

Answer (score 0):

Add and show result after assigning a string.

```
...
$query = "UPDATE subjects SET menu_name='{$menu_name}', position = '{$position}', visible='{$visible}' WHERE id='{$id}'";
var_dump($query);
...
```

Before you ask any question you should detect WHERE error is. Not just 'some one find bug in my code'... =\

Next step is to READ this page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html and find the difference... =\

Comment: you are right but error checks seems okey? : string(102) "UPDATE subjects SET menu_name = 'salam' position = 6 visible = 1 WHERE id = 80"

Comment: you code is thrash (is not a joke) so now we searching why is not updating am i right?